# get current contacts in android

Tags: android, contacts

I know that there been alot of questions about this issue.
but I can't found nothing that help me.
I know how to get all android contacts that have phone number by this code:

```
private List fillContactsList() {
        List tmpList = new ArrayList();

        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            String ContactID = c.getString(c
                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = c.getString(c
                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String hasPhone = c
                    .getString(c
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));
            if (Integer.parseInt(hasPhone) == 1) {
                Cursor phoneCursor = getContentResolver().query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                + "='" + ContactID + "'", null, null);
                while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                    String number = phoneCursor
                            .getString(phoneCursor
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    con = new Contact();
                    con.setName(name);
                    con.setNumber(number);
                    tmpList.add(con);
                }
                phoneCursor.close();
            }
        }
        c.close();
        Collections.sort(tmpList);

        return tmpList;
    }
```

The result of this on my device is 360 contacts but when I open my contact via the phone I see just 120. so How can I get just the group that currently showing on the contacts list on the phone?

Thanks!
Saar

Comment: What is currently being shown on the phone depends on the filter the user is using. You could get contacts by the filter rather than all contacts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if this is your problem or not, but you could try adding `IN_VISIBLE_GROUP` to your selection criteria. I don't remember the exact syntax off the top of my head, but it'd be something like this:

```
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(
               ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '1'", null, null);
```

Comment: bravissimo, i was spend 8 hours to understand it